# Manager cannot see Approve/Reject button on the Approval History why?

Tags: approval-process

I have two profiles Admin and Manager. Manager cant see the Approve/Reject button on the Approval History Section, but Admin can see it what could be the issue ?

**Note:  I have deployed Approval Process from Dev to UAT, also double check the Profile settings. Not sure why such decrepency coming ?**

[image]

**But Admin can see it**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to this issue and able to fixed it. Now I can see `Approve/Reject` button. Actually we're using the Public Group named as `Heath Supervisors`, in this group I was not added my Supervisors, when I added that they can see  `Approve/Reject` links.

Actually we are using queues and all Risk & Legal cases goes under that queue.